# Error with geom_segment, Can't add `o` to a ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a lollipop plot, but I am getting this error that I can't figure out.

```
temp = structure(list(group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
                                "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"), median = c(3, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1.1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                     1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
                                                                                                    13L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 12L), class = "data.frame")
ggplot(temp, aes(x=group, y=median)) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=group, xend=group, y=0, yend=median), color="black") +
  geom_point( aes ( color=group), size=10, alpha=0.75) +
  theme_light()
```

The error is:

> Error: Can't add `o` to a ggplot object

I isolated it to the geom_segment part. Since I commented that out, ggplot will plot as usual.
Is there something strange I'm not seeing? thanks.

addendum: I'm thinking this might be a conflict with another loaded package but I can't seem to isolate it to which one.  Further inspection this was the error msg.

> ```
> Backtrace:
>  1. GGally:::`+.gg`(...)
>  2. e1 %+% e2
>  3. ggplot2:::add_ggplot(e1, e2, e2name)
>  5. ggplot2:::ggplot_add.list(object, p, objectname)
>  6. plot %+% o
>  7. ggplot2:::add_ggplot(e1, e2, e2name)
>  9. ggplot2:::ggplot_add.default(object, p, objectname)
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> ```

2nd addendum, as per below the solution was to find out which package was conflicting by using library ( conflicted )

> ```
>     Error: [conflicted] `geom_segment` found in 2 packages.
> Either pick the one you want with `::` 
> * ggbio::geom_segment
> * ggplot2::geom_segment
> Or declare a preference with `conflict_prefer()`
> * conflict_prefer("geom_segment", "ggbio")
> * conflict_prefer("geom_segment", "ggplot2")
> ```

to fix this I just chose

```
conflict_prefer("geom_segment", "ggplot2")
```

that's it working fine now.

Comment: I don't get any errors when I ran the code, maybe restart r?

Comment: @Bruno hmm its strange; I'm thinking this might be a conflict with another loaded package but I can't seem to isolate it to which one.

Comment: Try it by layers, isolate which ggplot layer has stopped working, try to make explicit calls on that layer

Comment: try library(conflicted) and run your code, it should warn you of conflicts

Comment: @Bruno Bingo! thank you so much it works beautifully.  This will come in very handy.

Comment: I could not paste the codes correctly but pretty much what @Bruno said, loaded conflicted and was able to isolate the issue, then amazingly was able to fix the conflict without unloading the package.